# ItemClickListener on GridView not working

Tags: android, gridview, listener, adapter, onitemclicklistener

The aim of my app is to search for a song (deezer sdk)and display the result of the search in a gridView. I want to be able to have the cover of the album and the "artist - title" just below. As the "artist-title" may sometime be very long, I want to be able to scroll it horizontally. I've seen on the internet that I had to set the item as "focusable=false" but that doesn't seem to change anything.
The XML of the items inside my gridview looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/gridView_topLayout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/gridView_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:contentDescription="@string/gridTextView_Album"
    android:src="@drawable/album_cover_default" />

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/gridView_horizontalScroll"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:clipChildren="true"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridView_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gridView_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:singleLine="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

I know that is probably not the best way to do it but that's the only way I've managed to do it.
My adapter works perfectly as the album's cover are displayed as intended and the artist-title works great too.

This is the setOnItemClickListener inside my activity:

```
gridview.setAdapter(songSelection_adapter_listAdapter);
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3)
{
    Log.i("onItemClickListener", "CLICK!");
}
});
```

This doesn't ever print "click!" in the logcat, nothing happens.
I've tried with a "onTouchListener", which works great but I can't scroll my gridView down :(

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `ItemClickListener` for items of GridView in it's adapter,instead of set an ItemClickListener directly for GridView.

Comment: Well... I placed the listener inside the getView() of my custom adapter and it works. The only thing is that it's triggered only when I click on the image, not on the full gridview's cell.
Though, I agree with raghynandan, I don't understand why it doesn't work in the activity (everywhere on the internet I've seen the listener in the activity :x)

Comment: In case you don't want the adapter to know what happens when an item is clicked, this is not a good approach.